# Middleware is not called in Next.js Project

Tags: next.js, middleware

I am very new to Next.js. I am building a project in Next.js 13. The basic jist of the project is as follows. Client component sends data to server component, and than server component gets data from external API, server component gets data back from external URL, does some logic on it, and sends data to client components to be displayed. I am tinkering with the concept of middleware, but for some odd reason my middleware component is not responding at all. When I type "http://localhost:3000/test" I get an a 404 error. My file structure. my middleware function is very simple, it just returns a hello there json object. The middleware inside the app folder does not respond as well. It also has the same code as the one inside of 'test' folder. I thought initially that maybe its my browser that is the problem, so I tried postman and I am getting an error there as well, and not receiving a json object

[image: File structure]

[image: Browser]

[image: middleware code]

Answer (score 2):

Your middleware intercepts every single request, you probably do not want it to return that json - it's not like an API endpoint. I hadn't seen before but you've added a res with type NextApiResponse - that isn't right (because middleware isn't an API endpoint)

You'll typically want it to return either the request it was sent, or redirect it somewhere else if it hasn't passed the validation that you want (ie like the token is invalid, or something like that) either Response or NextResponse.

Eg, lifting the example from the NextJS Docs you can see the below. This would redirect the request to /home, here it would redirect all requests to home. So they actually include a matcher on the doc page (linked below) which only intercepts some requests.

```
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
    import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
     
    // This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
    export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
    }
```

NextJS's Docs can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).

When you're using middleware it's also important to remember it's not a typical serverless function, it's why you'll see some libraries or imports will not run in it because middleware needs to be super fast so you tend to want to do as little as possible in it.

If you really want to return a response with a body, instead of getting them to a page you can do:

```
  return NextResponse.json(
    { success: false, message: 'authentication failed' },
    { status: 401 }
  )
```

See [Returning a Response](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response) specifically in that area of the documentation.

Comment: point noted, but why am I not getting a json response back on the localhost:3000/test route? I should be seeing a json object at least. I was planning on having one middleware at the root, and than redirect it to other server components where data will be fetched from a API, but when I had middleware at the root, I didnt get a response, so I tried a test route and put middleware inside the test folder to see if it would work, and it doesnt work. What explains that?

Comment: Yes, you will only have 1 middleware and that can have branching logic. But it's a bit weird to make that middleware your router. Also, "other sever components" middleware is not a server component - it's a serverless edge function with a stripped down run time.

With your middleware the way it is, returning that JSON, your middleware is preventing the req.url from getting passed through. It's causing an error 'during' the request for want of a better word.

Comment: understood, but what explains me not getting a json object back at the /test url link?

Comment: Middleware return type isn't right here that may have misled you. I'm fairly sure req.status isn't a function so that will be the cause of the error. If you want to return a response you just want to return     return Response.json(
      { success: false, message: 'authentication failed' },
      { status: 401 }
    ) 

See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response

Comment: I did what you said, but I am still getting 404 on the /test url. I just commented out the res.status(200).json..... part and replaced it with "Response.json({test:"TESTING!!", message:"I hope this works"})" , I am still getting nothing

Comment: If you just commented out res.status and replaced it with that you're not returning it. You need to return the response. Here is the documentation, on the specific section of Producing a Response, have you looked at this and tried copying that in? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response

Comment: oh sory, forgot the return. Added the return but still nothing "return Response.json({test:"TESTING!!", message:"I hope this works"})"

Comment: If you copy and paste the example from the documentation, the whole thing, as your middleware what do you see? If you're not familiar with something I personally find it useful to start with something I know works, like something from the documentation, and then break it from there.

Comment: I copied pasted the return response under the "Producing a Response" subsection of the documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response) Still I am getting 404 on the /test  URL link

Comment: Can you throw up a jsfiddle or similar of your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nug9ac87/

Comment: You have not copied and pasted the **working** example from the documentation. You still have API types there. As say: start from something you know works instead of trying to get there backwards.

Comment: Did that. Litereally copied pasted the code from the doc, still nothing https://jsfiddle.net/u618oe0f/1/

Comment: Your JSFiddle isn't a working example so I can't replicate anything with it. However, if by 'nothing' you mean nothing when you go to the path /test - that's expected because the middleware isn't being called - the matcher. 

I suggest you actually read the documentation I have directed you to several times now. If you want to understand how something works and you're planning to be s software engineer you're going to have to get used to reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The tutorial I was following used an older version of next which allowed navigation to a middleware. Recently, they have revoked it so now you can only have one middleware (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide)